# realm migration issue on android

Tags: react-native, realm

I am trying to run multiple migrations on clean React Native android app.
But i get this error. The code works on iOS though.

"Unable to open a realm at path '.management'"

My schemas:

```
schemas = [
    { schema: [Order, Settings] },
    { schema: [Order, Settings], schemaVersion: 1, migration: schemaVersion1Migration }
];

let nextSchemaIndex = Realm.schemaVersion(Realm.defaultPath);
   while (nextSchemaIndex < schemas.length) {
      const migratedRealm = new Realm(schemas[nextSchemaIndex++]);
      migratedRealm.close();
   }

Realm.open(schemas[schemas.length-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Used try catch block to catch the exeception and continue on install.